# mobile app getting location via WiFi or 4G

Tags: mobile, gps, geolocation

I have a mobile application that need geo location data.
Mobile app can be used indoor or outdoor.  For outdoor,
there's GPS signals which works great.

For indoor, I am getting geo location data on and off.
Sometimes the data is good, sometimes it is not.  Other times,
I don't get any geo data.  The geo data must be coming from either 4G or Wifi 
but I do not understand how that works why is it not consistent.

Can anyone share your  knowledge about indoor geo location data from
from 4G/WiFi?   I am planning to cache the last known location but
if there's geo data that I can fetch when I am indoor, I won't need to do
any caching.
thanks

Comment: why reinvent the wheel? ios/android both already do location based on cell AND wifi data.

Comment: The issue is that location data via cell or wifi seems to be inconsistent.  There are times I receive no location data via those channels.  And I do not know why.